# Refreshing JWT in Postman

Tags: authorization, refresh, token, jwt, postman

We are new to token authorisation, in Postman we are able to get an access token but are unsure how to get a refresh token as we do not know where to obtain clientID, client secret etc. values from. We have already tried Auth0 but we do not want any front end in our application, we simply want to test it via rest client. If anyone can give us any ideas, we would be very grateful, 
Thanks

Comment: read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976677/should-i-explicitly-send-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token-jwt/44977875#44977875 maybe you find some useful information in it.

Comment: a sample code would be nice